# Measure of dispersion around the mode

Tags: density-function, mode, dispersion, central-tendency

I usually associate the standard deviation with the mean and the IQR with the median. Is there a measure of dispersion typically associated with the mode?

Comment: The width of the smallest interval containing half the data (the shortest half, or *shorth*) is sometimes used. See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/76848/retrieving-minimum-width-that-contains-specified-fraction-of-all-values

Comment: I don't think there is anything typical as a measure of dispersion.  If "the" mode -- however determined; that's a different story -- is quite different from the mean or median, then the main implication is that you need to report skewness too.

Comment: @Glen_b's helpful comment implies that the shortest half will contain the mode. In fact, that's not guaranteed, although it would be very common. (Counter-example: 0 has 40% of the values and is the mode. 9 and 10 have 30% of the values each.)

Comment: I’m looking for a generalized answer if possible, but right now, in particular, I’m looking for dispersion around the mode of a beta PDF that has shape parameters such that there is only one mode.

Comment: @Nick I definitely didn't intend to imply anything more than that the shortest half is sometimes used as a measure of spread along with the mode; there's certainly no guarantee that the interval would include the mode. Indeed, there may be several such shortest intervals and it may be that none of them include the mode. I agree there's no typical measure.

Comment: @Glen_b We agree completely.

Comment: If you're focusing on the beta distribution, then are you assuming that you know the parameters or are you trying to estimate them?

Comment: In the end I will be determining the parameters given a known mode and a known value for the dispersion metric, but constrained by the fact that PDF have a single peak. I’ve seen this done with the mean and variances on the beta PDF but for my purposes the mode is more intuitive and useful.

Comment: With a distribution thought to be (close to) beta, I would just use maximum likelihood (ML). This sounds like a homegrown method bound to be very sensitive to how you calculate the mode in the first place. With ML the mode is just estimated as a side-effect provided your parameter estimates are consistent with unimodality. On a different level, this thread is morphing into something quite different, so I suggest asking a new question.

Comment: I think the answer to this thread might be, “No, but you can try the shorth,” which is what I needed. But regarding the ML comment, I wouldn’t be calculating the mode. I would be supplying the location of the mode and the dispersion metric. For example, “What are the shape parameters of a unimodal Beta PDF given a mode at 0.8 and a [dispersion metric] of [number].” I could turn this into a new question. Let me think about it.

Comment: To be clear, I’m not fitting the PDF to data, I’m hypothesizing that the data be exactly a PDF with shape parameters I provide. Not sure I just made sense.

Comment: There are various ways to parameterise the beta distribution. I don't recall one that matches your view and it's hard to see that one could exist, as other parameters determine the mode when it's well-defined, but not _vice versa_.

Comment: I believe it can be done with the mode and some dispersion metric (right?). Perhaps the parameters can’t be solved for explicitly but it’s essentially two equations (mode and dispersion metric) and two unknowns (alpha and beta). It has definitely been done with mean and variance.

Comment: @Glen_b if you want to post your comment about the shorth with the caveat mentioned by Nick the I would accept that answer. Serious thanks to both of you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't really a typical measure of spread associated with the mode.

Of course one could calculate a root-mean-square-deviation-around-the-mode (a standard-deviation measure with the mode taken as the center) or a mean-absolute-deviation-around-the mode, but neither of those are common measures.

A measure of spread that is sometimes used with the mode is the width of the smallest interval containing half the data (the shortest half, or shorth). This measure is discussed by Nick Cox [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/76848/retrieving-minimum-width-that-contains-specified-fraction-of-all-values), but it isn't "about the mode" -- the shortest interval containing half the data needn't include the mode (indeed there may be multiple such intervals, and any or all of them may fail to include the mode).

However with a continuous [unimodal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unimodality), if mode and the shortest half are unique, then the shortest half will contain the mode (otherwise, some shortest half will contain a mode).

[Incidentally that linked article on unimodality *does* mention a result relating to the root mean square deviation around the mode, indicating that the first measure I mentioned does crop up in some situations.]

Answer (score 0):

Gauss proposed root mean square deviation from the mode, which is similar to the standard deviation, just replacing the mean with mode. He also proved that, asymptotically, for any unimodal distribution with a finite second moment, this root mean square deviation from the mode is between one standard deviation and two standard deviation.

Gauss, C. F. (1823). Theoria combinationis observationum erroribus minimis obnoxiae. Henricus Dieterich.

However, generally, this is an ill approach, because 1, if the distribution is not unimodal, than we can hardly choose which mode as the reference. 2, for non-asymptotic case, even for a unimodal distribution, the corresponding finite sample distribution is almost always not a perfect unimodal distribution, then, the same issue.

Generally, there are three nonparametric approaches to estimate the population dispersion: Quantile differences (Range/Interquartile range), Bickel-Lehmann dispersion (median absolute deviation, standard deviation, average absolute deviation, any estimators defined using a location estimator to estimate the deviations of all points relative to the location estimate of the sample can be seen in this class), and Bickel-Lehmann spread (besides the estimators proposed in Bickel and Lehmann's landmark paper, the popular Rousseeuw–Croux estimator and Gini's mean difference also can be seen in this class since they are a modification of the pairwise differences).

Estimators belong to the class, Bickel-Lehmann spread, are the optimal approach in terms of variance, but their computational cost is often much higher than others.

This is because the variance is mainly dependent on the sample size/pseudo sample size, this principle is governed by the Central Limit Theorem (although CLT is about the sample mean, the principle can be extended to other estimators, asymptotic normality).

Suppose the sample size is n, the median absolute deviation is essentially estimating the median of all n absolute deviations, so, the pseudosample size, i.e., the acutual size related to the median is also n. The Bickel-Lehmann spread is the location of all n^2 pairwise differences, so the pseudosample size is n^2. The quantile differences (Range/Interquartile range) is just computing two quantiles, so the pseudosample size is 2. A rough comparison of the pseudosample size can immediately conclude that, in terms of variance, quantile differences>Bickel-Lehmann dispersion>Bickel-Lehmann spread.

Comment: This is a bit spare by our standards. While the exposition about Gauss is useful, the answer contains no information to explain why the Bickel-Lehmann spread is optimal in terms of variance. Instead, readers are directed to your YouTube channel. This is now how this site works: answers should not be a platform for self-promotion, and they should contain relevant explanations. Citing works is fine & encouraged, but answers should summarize the key points.

Comment: Thank you. I explain that, it is because of the psudosample size of Bicke-Lehamnn spread is much higher than others.

Comment: Is it your intention to promote your own publications and YouTube channel in every answer that you write here?

Comment: Because these are new results, citation is needed, I already deleted the YouTube Channel.